# Rearranging equations to find value

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the question " Calculate the following quantity by first rearranging an appropriate equation.

$V$ when $u = -4.52 \frac m s$, $s = 61.3m$, and $t = 37.8s$"

So I have used the equation $s = \frac12(u+v)t$ and when rearranged to make the subject $V$, I got $V =\frac{2s-u}t$.

However, when I put the values in I get two different units for for s and u and I know that you cannot add numbers with different units so would I have to change the unit for s which is M to the same unit for u which is $\frac m s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You re-arranged incorrectly

Let $s=\frac{1}{2}(u+v)t$
Then
\begin{align}
2s &= (u+v)t, \qquad \text{multiplying by 2}\\
\implies \frac{2s}{t} &= u+v, \qquad \text{dividing by t}\\
\implies \frac{2s}{t}-u &= v 
\end{align}
Remember $s$ is a distance and $t$ is a time so the units of $\frac{s}{t}$ are $\frac{[L]}{[T]}=ms^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

It's $V=\frac{2s}t-u$. You should have divided by $t$ earlier.